# Can condition that a*b>a where (a>b) promise computation without overflow?

Tags: integer-overflow

Problem: given two integers a, b (a>b) and the only data type can be used is `int`; besides compiler adopt two's complement computation method.

1. Can a*b>a promise the result a*b is right without overflow?
2. If the answer is yes, how can I prove? otherwise, how to find counterexample and what's the right condition?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in part, in the C# program

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int a = 654321;
        int b = -654321;
        var iBool = a * b > a;
        Console.WriteLine(iBool);
    }
}
```

the condition `a * b > a` evalues to `true`, which is analytically wrong. `b` is negative and `a` is positive, so `a*b` must be negative, but of larger absolute value than `b`, which means that `a*b` cannot be larger than `a`. However, the implementation decides otherwise.

Comment: Note that `b` cannot be positive if `a` is negative since the precondition says two integers `a, b (a>b)`.

Comment: Good point about `b` alone being negative too, by the way. I only considered the both-are-negative case, but this one is definitively possible within the preconditions, too.

Answer (score 0):

### No.

Let's look at positive numbers first. In order for the promise to be wrong, the overflow must be so large that it not only overflows but is larger than `a`, so something well in excess of twice `INT_MAX` would be needed (to be precise it needs to be something larger than `abs(INT_MIN)+INT_MAX+a`).

*Intuitively* that looks like it can't happen, but it is not as impossible as it seems because `a` and `b` only both need to be significantly larger than one half the bit size of `int`, but not too close to the maximum.

It's easier to see that the promise doesn't hold with negative `a` and `b`. The precondition `a > b` implies that if `a` is negative, then `b` is negative as well, and thus the result of multiplying them is always positive.

Positive numbers are **always** larger than negative numbers, no matter which numbers you choose, so `a*b > a` is always true whenever `a` and `b` are both negative, you always promise no overflow has happened, regardless of whether that is the case.

Except, well except when `a` and `b` are small enough, integer overflow *will happen*.

Take any two non-special, but decidedly negative integers, say -5'000'000 and -500'000, which fulfill the precondition `a > b`.
Multiply them and you get 2'500'000'000'000 which is significantly overflowing (several times, actually).
The result is 329033728, which is definitively larger than -5'000'000, so you wrongly promise that no overflow has happened.